# Database Performance/Maximum Columns

Tags: mysql, performance, database-design, entity-attribute-value

Nowadays I developed a website for a science project which works like a documentation.
That means their is one person and 1200 possible informations (columns in my database, like age, job etc..) which might be collected.Realistically less information will be collected because most of them are radio-buttons and checkboxes, so it will be about 300 details per person.

For 1 person their are basically 5 different question papers.
3 of the question papers will be asked 3 times again during the 4 years of study. So you can see afterwards a history how things went.

After all information and data about 400 people (rows filled with their values) are collected a statistic program should help to make some interesting statistics about the study.

I am just concerned about the performance and usability. So my question:

Is it fine to have one table with 1200 columns (possible information) for 400 rows (people)?

I read about normalization and basically it make sense for a business like:
1 person with his personal details (1 table) buys a chocolate (another table) with information about the chocolate. They are separated because its not sure if he buys the chocolate, so just for the case he buys the chocolate its good to have 2 tables which have a connection in that case finally.

In my case all columns are every time related to the person (because its like a survey) and I want that its easy for the statistic program to find the information instead of searching in for example 6 different tables.

First I had InnoDB until I realized it will be more then 1000 columns, so I switched to MyISAM.
I tried to safe a lot of storage by specifying the columns very detailed with type and length. Which is to 70 percent INT (1).

I appreciate your help very much.

Comment: The questions should be rows, not columns

Comment: you mean one row is to long because of the 1200 columns?

Comment: you should consider that each radio group is a single record (column) that can have different values (the radio options). So a radio group with 5 options you will have one column and not 5 for that radio.

Comment: Thank you, I did that already the way how you say. And why I might have less informations: I meant they asked me for example for a table where they wanted to have a checkbox for each of 30 different cases because 1 or up to 30 can happen.

Comment: Read several Q&As tagged 'entity-attribute-value', then come back.

Comment: Read about `TINYINT`, it takes only 1 byte; `INT(1)` takes 4 bytes.